# Change File Attribute in windows

Tags: filesystems, file-management

I have basically two images :
1. one with jpeg and file "attributes" as 'N' as seen below :
[image]

Now i m trying to create image with same property but whenever i create new image or edit the same image the attribute chnages to 'A'. can anyone please tell me how to replicte same image property and create a new image in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**N** stands for *Normal* ([FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 128 (0x80)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). According to Microsoft, it  signifies:

```
A file that does not have other attributes set. This attribute is valid only when used alone.
```

So the only way to set **N** is to clear all other attributes. At the command prompt just type:

```
attrib -h -a -i -r -s <file name>
```

to end up with **N** in Windows Explorer.

Comment: will this command work on windiws?

Comment: Huh? `attrib` has always worked in Windows! BTW, *why* do you want to create an image with the N attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Attributes 'A' and 'N' stand for archived and not content indexed. They have to do with what the OS sees to do with the file; here's a good discussion around the 'N' attribute. https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/microsoft.public.windows.vista.general/QC26y9h4Lw4

Follow this to toggle the N attribute, though it may not be immediate:

> Right-click the file > Properties > Advanced > Check / Uncheck the
>   'Index  this file / folder ...' option and you'll see it disappear /
>   appear

Comment: there is no option of "index this file / folder...." and i tired all options avaiable there it chnages to 'AI','I'...but not 'N'

Comment: Ahh Windows 7 does not have that checkbox anymore apparently and it can only be set at the folder level or with the attrib -r -a -s -h  file.whatever. You use the command prompt, navigate to the folder with the file, and then type: attrib -r -a -s -h filename

Comment: @Abraxas Win7 explorer can only change the index properties at the drive level (not even the folder level)

Comment: You're right, i was referring to the indexing tool in windows 7 t o do that. But since they are only using it for a specific file I didn't post additional details. https://superuser.com/questions/591406/how-do-i-disable-indexing-in-a-specific-directory-across-multiple-platforms

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xcopy command with a flag (`/K`) to retain attributes. Example: `xcopy \K C:\path\to\file\picture.jpg newpicture.jpg`

Here's more on Xcopy and other flags for retaining permissions, etc...
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323007

There's also a small portable NirSoft utility that will allow you to individually or bulk change file properties. [Here](http://nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html)